# DNS GetHostEntry - How to Specify DNS Server? .NET

Tags: .net, dns

In .NET you can make a call to

```
 Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)
```

This uses the DNS entries on your NETWORK Settings to do the DNS Look up, but I would like to specify the DNS Server `8.8.8.8` to do the look up against, without changes the DNS Settings in the NETWORK Settings.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12072/C-NET-DNS-query-component) component.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing build into .NET yet, but there are NuGet packages you can use which do an actual DNS lookup against a DNS server of your choice.

[DnsClient.NET](http://dnsclient.michaco.net) is one of those. It also has methods to create a host entry with similar syntax.

Example:

```
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(NameServer.GooglePublicDns);    
var lookup = new LookupClient(endpoint);

IPHostEntry hostEntry = lookup.GetHostEntry(hostOrIp);
Console.WriteLine(hostEntry.HostName);
foreach (var ip in hostEntry.AddressList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ip);
}
foreach (var alias in hostEntry.Aliases)
{
    Console.WriteLine(alias);
}
```